# Почему в JSlider не показывается шкала и цифры? Отображается только ползунок

Tags: java, swing, gui

Почему в JSlider не показывается шкала и цифры? Отображается только ползунок.
В программе слайдер должен отображать и то и другое.
Вот код:

```
public class Test extends JFrame { 
    Test(){
        JToolBar tb = new JToolBar("Панель ирструментов", JToolBar.HORIZONTAL);
        add(tb, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JSlider sl = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 20, 6);
        sl.setPaintTicks(true);
        sl.setPaintLabels(true);
        sl.setPaintTrack(true);
        tb.add(sl);

        this.setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Повторюсь, слайдер отображается, а шкала и цифры почему-то нет.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решился путем добавления

```
sl.setMinorTickSpacing(2);
sl.setMajorTickSpacing(6);
```